# AWS "state file" solution for Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm using a library in lambda where a "state file" is persisted

This is what it looks like in code:

```
def initialize
  @config = '/tmp/dogscaler.yaml'
  @state = self.load
end
```

If you need to look at the whole logic

- https://github.com/cvent/dogscaler/blob/master/lib/dogscaler/state.rb#L5

My issue is that, this won't work in lambda (it being serverless). I'm trying to look for a solution where I don't have to change the logic in how the file is read and modifed.

Can this be achieved with `S3`?

Would something like this pseudo code work?

```
read s3://path/to/file
write s3://path/to/file
```

Are there better solutions to `S3`?

**Additional Context**

The file is needed for a cooldown period logic. Every time the application runs, it would check a time stamp from that file to make a judgement on wether to change an element or not. File is less than 1KB.

Comment: I think we need a little more context here. What are you doing with the "state file"? S3 may be a valid option, depending on the use case.

Comment: We are updating a yaml file every run

Comment: You certainly could write a YAML (or JSON) file to S3 but DynamoDB might be a better fit. Lower latency, automated TTL.

Comment: Updating it for use elsewhere? In that case S3 is probably your best bet. You do run the risk of data being overwritten when two request come in at the same time, so be sure to set the concurrency on your lambda to 1.

Comment: Parameter Store would be a good option.

Comment: Parameter Store has a size limit of 4 KB. If you are constantly appending to the file you'll run into that sooner rather than later. I think the point here is that there are several via options, but without knowing how the data is being used it's hard to know what you should do.

Comment: 4 KB is more than enough. the file is needed for a cooldown period. So every time the application runs, it would check a time stamp from that file to make a judgement on wether to change an element or not

Comment: Each parameter has a 4KB limit but you can use multiple parameters, and it's hierarchical. If you're storing more than 4KB per item then a) you probably shouldn't be (state should be minimal) ;-) and b) a different store is required (like DDB or S3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the updated information you could store the data in a number of places.

**S3** would be perfectly fine, but might be overkill if this is all you're using it for.

The same can be said of **DynamoDB**.

**Parameter Store** is a solid option for your use case. Bear in mind that if you are calling it often you may need to increase your TPS limit. It doesn't sound like that will be an issue for you. Also keep in mind that there is no protection here for multiple instances of your Lambda function writing to the parameter at the "same time." The last write will win. If you need to protect against that DynamoDB is probably the best option.